# HTML/CSS: Make Border-right height dynamic

Tags: html, css

I am dealing with a big huge legacy code so this is why the HTML is badly styled. I have to work with what I have so I don't really want to try and fix it and mess up everything.

I am trying to make the border-right height dynamic (that takes the longest height of the columns).

Here is the jsfiddle I am working with: http://jsfiddle.net/XmKrm/616/

```
<div id="MAIN">
<div id="ColumnOne">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>111  <br/>
      111</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="ColumnTwo">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="ColumnThree">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
    <td>333 333 <br> 333 <br> 333 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="ColumnFour">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>444 444 <br> 444 444 <br> 444 444 <br> 444 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#ColumnOne,
#ColumnTwo,
#ColumnThree,
#ColumnFour {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Are these divs in a wrapper?

Comment: yes, edited. added <div id="main">

Comment: Your fiddle does not match your code...did you link the wrong one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#ColumnOne,
#ColumnTwo,
#ColumnThree,
#ColumnFour {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="ColumnOne">
  <div class="Coltop">SAMPLE TITLE</div>
  <div class="ColMid">
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td>111
          <br/> 111
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="ColumnTwo">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="ColumnThree">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>333 333
        <br> 333
        <br> 333
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="ColumnFour">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>444 444
      <br> 444 444
      <br> 444 444
      <br> 444 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hello you might have some other conflicting css, Try to remove float if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that

```css
#ColumnOne,
#ColumnTwo,
#ColumnThree,
#ColumnFour {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  float: left;
}
#MAIN {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="MAIN">

  <div id="ColumnOne">
    <div class="Coltop">SAMPLE TITLE</div>
    <div class="ColMid">
      <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
          <td>111
            <br/>111
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ColumnTwo">
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td>222</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="ColumnThree">
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td>333 333
          <br>333
          <br>333</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="ColumnFour">
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td>444 444
          <br>444 444
          <br>444 444
          <br>444</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use use the jQuery [`height`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) method to get the heights of each column, put them into an array, then use JavaScript [`Math.max`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp) function to compute the max height:

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [
    $("#ColumnOne").height(),
    $("#ColumnTwo").height(),
    $("#ColumnThree").height(),
    $("#ColumnFour").height()
  ];
  $("#ColumnOne, #ColumnTwo, #ColumnThree, #ColumnFour").height(Math.max.apply(Math, arr));
});
```

```css
#ColumnOne,
#ColumnTwo,
#ColumnThree,
#ColumnFour {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ColumnOne">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>111
        <br/>111
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="ColumnTwo">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>222</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="ColumnThree">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>333 333
        <br>333
        <br>333</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="ColumnFour">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>444 444
        <br>444 444
        <br>444 444
        <br>444</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```